# PHP - Getting One Piece of Date from ini file (from a url)

Tags: php, ini

I am still getting used to php.  I am trying to get one piece of data from an ini url file to be used to change into a variable.

The example url where the ini file is stored is at http://jla.justiceleague.com/idinfo.jl/MMH001  (only example,non-working url)

The File looks like:

```
 ver=1
 id=MMH001
 name=John Jonz
 origin=Mars
 org=Justice League
 web=mars.martianmanhunter.com
```

What I am trying to do is obtain just the web url (aka the "mars.martianmanhunter.com" ) from the ini file and then turn it to a variable in php to use for later purposes.

So first how do we get connected to the ini file.  Most importantly, how do we only get that one piece of information that I need to obtain?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php or get it then http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use the parse_ini_string() function. Like this:

```
<?php

// Here you set the file/url
$url = 'http://jla.justiceleague.com/idinfo.jl/MMH001';

// Get the content of file/website
$webData = file_get_contents($url);

// Make $web and array of items in INI file
$web = parse_ini_string($webData);

// echo mars.martianmanhunter.com from the array
print_r($web['web']);
```

The array that "$web" contain will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [ver] => 1
    [id] => MMH001
    [name] => John Jonz
    [origin] => Mars
    [org] => Justice League
    [web] => mars.martianmanhunter.com
)
```

And if you don't want the entire array each time and just want the "web" variable in the ini file, then you do it like this:

```
$web = parse_ini_string($webData)['web'];
print_r($web);
```

Now "$web" will only contain "mars.martianmanhunter.com" and wont have get stuff like "id", "name" etc..

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was working for a bit, but all of a sudden I am receiving a proxy 502 error and my server is not a proxy..  I looked in the php error log and it is showing that I am receiving "PHP Warning:  file_get_contents : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"  Any help will be good!

Comment: Do your website run with SSL? (https)

Comment: Got it fixed... Had to add a curl to it.